# System.Web.Extensions Not Found Even After Installing ASP.Net AJAX

Tags: iis, asp.net

I'm deploying an ASP.Net web service to a VM running Windows Server 2008/IIS 7. I've installed the ASP.Net AJAX extensions (from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en)) on the server. However, when I attempt to access the service, I'm getting the following error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

I've already tried restarting IIS with no success. I can see that the System.Web.Extensions dll is present (at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Web.Extensions.dll`), but ASP.Net somehow isn't able to find it. Is there anything else I need to do in order to get ASP.Net to recognize that this DLL is present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that .Net Framework 3.5 is not installed by default on Windows Server 2008 R2. Running the installer for the .Net Framework 3.5 fixed the issue.